# Windows phone: Disadvantages on table rendering

Tags: html, css, windows-phone

I want to convert td's into tr's in responsive design.

I tried with display:block, float:left, width:100% within the media queries.
()

It is working good as expected in android devices.

But the Windows phone is not supporting this in any version.

How to make it working with Windows mobile?

Comment: Which browser are you using on windows phone? Can you post some prints, code, jsfiddle?

Comment: IE browser.

its Normal table structure with table, tr's, td's
.

Comment: FYI, Windows Mobile is a different operating system from Windows Phone.

Comment: Hi All,

I have concerns about how to make a td to fit the screen width in IE browser of windows mobile.

Suggestions pls.

Comment: Pls look into this screenshot and want to make same working in IE 6+ versions and Windows Mobile version also.

http://jsfiddle.net/anandselvam02/LpL3xenc/